# docker entrypoint running bash script gets "permission denied"

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I'm trying to dockerize my node.js app. When the container is built I want it to run a `git clone` and then start the node server. Therefore I put these operations in a .sh script. And run the script as a single command in the ENTRYPOINT:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev gcc curl npm git

#install gcc 4.9
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libstdc++-4.9-dev

#install newst nodejs
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ADD package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

ADD docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

My docker-entrypoint.sh looks like this:

```
git clone git@<repo>.git
git add remote upstream git@<upstream_repo>.git

/usr/bin/node server.js
```

After building this image and run:

```
docker run --env NODE_ENV=development -p 8080:8080 -t -i <image>
```

I'm getting:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: exec: "/usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh": permission denied.
```

I shell into the container and the permission of docker-entrypoint.sh is:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 292 Aug 10 18:41 docker-entrypoint.sh
```

three questions:

1. Does my bash script have wrong syntax?
2. How do I change the permission of a bash file before adding it into an image?
3. What's the best way to run multiple git commands in entrypoint without using a bash script?

Thanks.

Comment: We need to see the file permissions to be able to answer this question.

Comment: BTW, if this is a **bash** script, not a **sh** script, a `.sh` extension leaves a misleading impression about which interpreters can execute it. You might consider taking that out -- it's not conventional for UNIX commands to have extensions (you don't run `ls.elf`, for instance).

Comment: Can we `exec` a shell that way? wouldn't it need the `bash` prefix.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, what exactly do you mean by your question? (I don't understand what "exec a shell that way" means -- what's "that way" in this context?)

Comment: Silly question, by the way -- are the script's permissions correct *before* you add them to the image?

Comment: (...btw, editing a question in a way that makes a previously-given answer no longer make sense is frowned on a bit).

Comment: I mean: if I perform a exec of a script not within a shell, it refuses to execute. It works if the exec uses a shell to run. But maybe that's already covered.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, that's something that happens when you don't have a valid shebang: Many shells will assume that a file with the executable bit set but no valid shebang (for which the `execv` call fails, meaning the OS can't figure out how to execute it) should be executed as a script with that shell itself, and will fall back to doing so, but the operating system won't make that assumption and will simply refuse to execute content without a proper shebang.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, ...so, the simple mechanism to avoid that behavior is to ensure that your scripts always start with `#!/bin/bash` (if bash), `#!/bin/sh` (if POSIX sh), etc.

Comment: I encountered similar issue. However, running `RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"]` doesn't work for me. It only works when i change the permission from my local source directory. I'm not sure why I can't change the executable permission from Dockerfile. Does anybody have similar issue ?

Answer (score 374, accepted):

1. "Permission denied" prevents your script from being invoked *at all*. Thus, the only syntax that could be possibly pertinent is that of the first line (the "shebang"), which should look like `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, or `#!/bin/bash`, or similar depending on your target's filesystem layout.
2. Most likely the filesystem permissions not being set to allow execute. It's also possible that the shebang references something that isn't executable, but this is *far* less likely.
3. Mooted by the ease of repairing the prior issues.

---

The simple reading of

```
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: exec: "/usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh": permission denied.
```

...is that the script isn't marked executable.

```
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

will address this within the container. Alternately, you can *ensure that the local copy referenced by the Dockerfile is executable*, and then use `COPY` (which is explicitly documented to retain metadata).

Comment: I think you are right. I should use COPY instead. But it seems I still need to change the permission after COPYing the bash script.

Comment: I have a phar file that creates .bash scripts based on a command and then removes them once they have completed. So the need for shared volumes to have the execute permission set is something I'm still struggling with.

Comment: @raupie, if you want to run a script off a mount point with the `noexec` flag, run `bash yourscript` instead of `./yourscript`.

Comment: I don't undertand, when I run `docker build` the imtermediate container works fine. But when I do `docker run`, it throws such error. Seems like a magical intermediate container I have got.

Comment: Neither RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"] nor RUN ["chmod", "a+x", "/usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"] did change the permissions in my docker image, it's still '-rw-r--r-- '

Comment: @niid, if you create a question with a Dockerfile that acts as a [mre] for the issue, feel free to @-notify me there.

Comment: "Alternately, you can ensure that the local copy referenced by the Dockerfile is executable"


is the way to go if you're using rootless docker images (Since you won't be having permission to run `chmod` in the first place).

Answer (score 100):

An executable file needs to have permissions for execute set before you can execute it.

In your machine where you are building the docker image (not inside the docker image itself) try running:

```
ls -la path/to/directory
```

The first column of the output for your executable (in this case docker-entrypoint.sh) should have the executable bits set something like:

```
-rwxrwxr-x
```

If not then try:

```
chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh
```

and then build your docker image again.

Docker uses it's own file system but it copies everything over (including permissions bits) from the source directories.

Comment: `chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh` on tzhe host is actually the recommended solution, as it is much simpler than changing your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: This worked for me. I did not really understand why though xD. If you reader end up in this at some point, I would appreciate the reasons behind this.

Comment: if you have a posix compatible filesystems (i.e. you run macos or linux or some bsd) then you docker will copy the rights from the host. on windows, for example, you don't have those, so it will just add them.

Answer (score 57):

I faced same issue & it resolved by

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

For the Dockerfile in the original question it should be like:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: This is a workaround, but not a great one -- this interprets the script with `sh`, ignoring its shebang's specification of an interpreter; so if it uses `#!/bin/bash`, saying it wants to be interpreted with bash, that will be ignored and it'll be interpreted with `sh` instead, thus disallowing language features like `[[ ]]`, arrays, etc.

Comment: I've used your approach and it worked. Maybe also dos2unix does the trick

Comment: This approach is the one that worked for me. I wonder what is the reason behind it.

Comment: thank you, save me hours upon hours of research!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What would be right solution instead?

Comment: @FernandoTorres, set the entrypoint to be _the script itself_. `ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint"]` ([`.sh` extensions are bad practice](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/)) -- with a valid shebang line specifying the interpreter to use, and `+x` permissions so that shebang gets used.

Answer (score 43):

The problem is due to **original file not having execute permission.**

**Check original file has permission.**

run `ls -al`

If result get `-rw-r--r--` ,

run
`chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh`

before docker build!

Comment: I was chasing this for an hour! Thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 24):

### Remove Dot [.]

This problem take with me more than 3 hours finally, I just tried the problem was in removing **dot** from the end just.

problem was

```
docker run  -p 3000:80 --rm --name test-con test-app .
```

> /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: 8: exec: .: Permission denied

just remove **dot** from the end of your command line :

```
docker run  -p 3000:80 --rm --name test-con test-app
```

Comment: 2023 I don't think this is working anymore

Comment: Real easy to have the . at the end... if you edit the "docker build" command and then change it to the "docker run" command.

Comment: Can't believe I upvoted a typo answer, but yes, the extra dot was the issue :)

Answer (score 9):

Grant execution rights to the file `docker-entrypoint.sh`

```
sudo chmod 775 docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: When we write dockerfile we try to run the script sometimes, so the script must have proper rights to run, while docker creates an image. 'docker-entrypoint.sh'

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit stupid maybe but the error message I got was Permission denied and it sent me spiralling down in a very wrong direction to attempt to solve it. (Here for example)

I haven't even added any bash script myself, I think one is added by nodejs image which I use.

```
FROM node:14.9.0
```

I was **wrongly** running to expose/connect the port on my local:

```
docker run -p 80:80 [name] . # this is wrong!
```

which gives

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: 8: exec: .: Permission denied
```

But you shouldn't even have a dot in the end, it was added to documentation of another projects docker image by misstake. **You should simply run**:

```
docker run -p 80:80 [name]
```

I like Docker a lot but it's sad it has so many gotchas like this and not always very clear error messages...

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue. This works for me.

```
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do *not* use DockerFile, you can simply add permission as command line argument of the bash:

```
docker run -t <image>  /bin/bash -c "chmod +x /usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh; /usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question asked two years prior to my answer, I am going to post what worked for me anyways.

In my working directory I have two files: Dockerfile & provision.sh

Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:6.8

# put the script in the /root directory of the container
COPY provision.sh /root

# execute the script inside the container
RUN /root/provision.sh

EXPOSE 80

# Default command
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

provision.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

yum upgrade
```

I was able to make the file in the docker container executable by setting the file outside the container as executable `chmod 700 provision.sh` then running `docker build .` .

Answer (score 0):

If you still get `Permission denied` errors when you try to run your script in the docker's entrypoint, just try **DO NOT** use the **shell form** of the entrypoint:

Instead of:
`ENTRYPOINT ./bin/watcher` write `ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/watcher"]`:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had 4 mysql docker images which was the cause. Removed them all & did a fresh image install.

```
docker images -a | grep "mysql" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi -f
```

Answer (score 0):

As most of our friends suggested to,YES its a permission issue and adding following line in your dockerfile should help.

```
chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Although there is a catch If by any chance you have used **`volume mounts`** and in your **`host machine it is not marked as a executable file`**. the **`entrypoint permissions will be overridden`** by the host machine file permission.

which means you `chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh` wont have any effect inside the container.
Resulting in the error `docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: exec: "/usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh": permission denied.`

To avoid this you can simply **`give execute permission on host machine`** itself or you can just run the command using the bash i.e

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Hope it saves someones time :)

Answer (score -2):

In my case, the path of `server.js` in Dockerfile was not correct, when we give proper path to the `CMD`, then you might not face this issue. build has been created successfully. just check from making directory

```
RUN mkdir -p /home/app
COPY . /home/app
CMD ["node", "/home/app/index.js"]
```

My previous version was `CMD["node","index.js"]`

Comment: This answer doesn't really match the question: since you're explicitly giving the `node` interpreter as part of the `CMD`, details like the file permissions or line endings matter less.  (You also don't need to `RUN mkdir` before you `COPY` a file into a directory; and if you set `WORKDIR` to the target directory, then you can `COPY . .` without repeating the directory name, and your original `CMD` will work.)