# /bin/sh: /root/start-docker.sh: Permission denied when exec command in docker

Tags: docker

I am copy script into docker container when build,this is part of my Dockerfile:

```
ADD soa-room-service/build/libs/soa-room-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /soa-room-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD script/start-docker.sh /root/start-docker.sh

EXPOSE 13003
ENTRYPOINT /root/start-docker.sh
```

when I am running docker using this command:

```
docker run --name soa-room-service -d registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_product/soa-room:latest
```

this is docker logs output:

```
$ docker logs e62917af92ccf240c73574e71041229a65db54e29453723ba27d56bcf9856b9a
/bin/sh: /root/start-docker.sh: Permission denied
```

I am replace the path using ~ symbol.But it still give me Permission denied error.How to make it works?

Comment: Are you running this as root user? What are the permissions on /root/start-docker.sh? check with ls -l /root

Comment: Give executable permission to **start-docker.sh** before building the docker image

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882654/docker-entrypoint-running-bash-script-gets-permission-denied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `/root/start-docker.sh` in the internal docker filesystem lacks the permissions.
You might want to modify the Dockerfile:

```
ADD soa-room-service/build/libs/soa-room-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /soa-room-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD script/start-docker.sh /root/start-docker.sh

USER root 
RUN chmod 755 /root/start-docker.sh

EXPOSE 13003
ENTRYPOINT /root/start-docker.sh
```

Of course if you want to run the `/root/start-docker.sh` under another user, you can also run `RUN chown youruser:yourgroup /root/start-docker.sh`

Answer (score 4):

change ENTRYPOINT script like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/root/start-docker.sh"]
```